# Response Assertion JMeter on Array

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to get assert a response body from a list of objects that were deleted with AWS SDK, the scenario is this:

I use a Delete Http request to a endpoint passing an array, with a list of object names, then aws should return the list with the objects that were deleted, but it's not in the same order of the list that i've passed, so i'm using a Contains to see if the objects are in the response body.

[image]

[image]

Someone can help me? I think that is a problem with Regex from JMeter but I'm freeze with this.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Contains` pattern matching rule which expects the pattern to be a [Perl-5 compatible regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions)

In this case you will need to properly escape all the [meta characters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) either manually or using a [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) calling [Pattern.quote() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) instead:

```
${__groovy(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(vars.get('listOfObjects')),)}
```

If you want to check whether the response just contains your `${listOfObjects}` variable switch to `Substring` pattern matching rule

[image]